# Avoid memory allocations while getting neighbors in a DFS/BFS algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm writing some code which does a DFS of a grid map. One function that I call a lot is the getNeighbors(...) which gets all the neighbors of a specified cell:

```
public ArrayList<Point> getNeighbors(int i, int j) {
    ArrayList<Point> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Point n : upDownLeftRightDirections) {
        int dx = i + n.x;
        int dy = j + n.y;
        result.add(new Point(dx, dy));
    }
    return result;
}

... Later in the code ...

for (Point neighbor : getNeighbors(i, j)) {
    ... Do stuff ...
}
```

My question is that I feel this process seems wasteful to create a new list of neighbors every time a cell is processed, especially since the list of neighbors is only used once. Any suggestions for how to rewrite to avoid creating a new list each time - mainly to take advantage of the fact that I only need to iterate over the neighbors once per call?

Comment: The performance difference will be minimal. Having `getNeighbours` makes it significantly easier to maintain, so I see no issue with it. Would I be wrong in saying that this is premature optimisation?

Comment: Hmm yeah you might be right, I definitely agree there's probably bigger places to optimize first. The background context is I am writing an AI to play Go and the getNeighbors(...) function gets called in a lot of places in my code; I just want to make it fast because I plan on implementing a monte carlo tree search strategy for my bot which would benefit from optimization.

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions for how to rewrite to avoid creating a new list each time

You could declare the `result` list as an instance variable. This way, you can clear it everytime you finish iterating over the neighbors :

```
for (Point neighbor : results) {
    ... Do stuff ...
}
results.clear();
```

> mainly to take advantage of the fact that I only need to iterate over
>   the neighbors once per call?

You should benchmark your code to see whether this truly has a performance advantage over the previous approach.

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach could also work here; I am not familiar with the deeper semantics of Java, but something like:

```
public void consumeNeighbors(Function f) {
    for (Point n : upDownLeftRightDirections) {
        int dx = i + n.x;
        int dy = j + n.y;
        f(dx, dy);
    }
}
```

This would avoid creating new Point objects and a new List, while iterating over the neighbors. But again, it's not clear that this would offer significant savings, so it would require benchmarking to determine if it is worthwhile to refactor in this way.